# Completeness of infinite direct sums of Banach spaces: reference

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, banach-spaces, direct-sum

I am looking for a reference of the following fact:

Let $\left(X,\left\Vert \cdot\right\Vert \right)$ be a Banach space. For every $\left(x^{n}\right)_{n\geq0}\subseteq X$ define $$\left\Vert \left(x^{n}\right)_{n\geq0}\right\Vert _{\Sigma}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left\Vert x^{n}\right\Vert $$

and let$$\mathcal{X}=\left\{ \left(x^{n}\right)_{n\geq0}\subseteq X:\,\left\Vert \left(x^{n}\right)_{n\geq0}\right\Vert _{\Sigma}<\infty\right\} .$$Then $\left(\mathcal{X},\left\Vert \cdot\right\Vert _{\Sigma}\right)$ is complete. Any reference would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The proof would be similar to showing that $l_1$ is complete. In fact you could prove is using that fact.

Comment: @copper.hat Maybe it would, but I would prefer to cite a reference to some book or paper if that's available...

Comment: It is not a standard result, but not difficult to demonstrate either.

Comment: You are right, I just wanted to avoid filling my appendix with too many details so a reference would have been ideal. But thanks anyways, I appreciate your suggestion.